# Separate Client and Server in Jhipster Gateway

Tags: jhipster

I am implementing Microservice but want to separate Client from Jhipster Gateway so that can have modular model.
Can someone let me know how to separate client and server in Jhipster Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the follow command:

```
jhispter --skip-server
```

to create gateway service without frontend.

```
jhispter --skip-client --auth --db
```

to create gateway frontend withou service. but I don't know how set the parameter "--auth" "--db" yet. I just merge the code generated by

```
jhispter
```

to the frontend code. It works for me.