# Is there a way to have a seperate microservice for login in jhipster?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I noticed that when i generate a microservice gateway, the authentication service is a part of that gateway, can I have the authentication in its own microservice rather than have it generated along with the frontend code?

Comment: Have you tried with the --skip-client option?

Comment: @ecostanzi you're a genius man! That should do! I'll give it a try and see if that works.

Comment: That works! Can you add it as an answer so i mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a jhipster gateway without the frontend code by running

```
jhipster --skip-client
```

For this case the [jhipster documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/) states:

> This should only work well for monoliths, as this doesn’t make much sense for microservices (which have no front-end anyway) and gateways (which are basically a monolith with the Zuul gateway service enabled).

However, if you stick to JWT and you generate the app using the jdl you can also set `skipUserManagement` to true.

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType gateway,
    serviceDiscoveryType consul,
    authenticationType jwt,
    skipUserManagement false
    skipClient true
  }
}
```

Using this configuration all the User and Authentication related classes will not be generated. This is basically a gateway that will only route the requests to the microservices, without handling any authentication at all.

Interesting fact (if I'm not mistaken): if you disable the service discovery from the above configuration you will have exactly the same code as you would have in a microservice application.

Some related links:

- [Separate Client and Server in Jhipster Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107022/separate-client-and-server-in-jhipster-gateway)
- https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/

Answer (score 1):

Not directly with JWT, you have to code it manually. Otherwise you could choose another auth type option that uses external service like keycloak, uaa, or okta.